¿Cómo obtener todos los items de un layout o vista? en Kotlin
Estoy intentando meter en un ArrayList(String>() todos los ChekcBox marcados. No se como acceder de forma que no se tenga que ir de uno en uno.
Esto es un pequeño ejercicio y en este caso solo hay 3 checkBox, aún así me gustaría saber como se puede logra.
En el layout tengo esto: (borro los campos que no son necesarios para este caso para no meter mucho codigo)
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_opciones"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
     ...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/elige" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_uno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/primero" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_dos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/segundo" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_tres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/tercero" />
</LinearLayoutt>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_enviar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:text="@string/enviar"/>
...

Y el código con el que he hecho el apaño:
binding.btnEnviar.setOnClickListener {
        // Guardar valores de los campos
        ... 
        // Crear una lista para guardar lo items
        val checksSelect = ArrayList<String>()
        // Meter en una variable los items de la vista.
        val layoutItems = binding.llOpciones
        // Recorrer los items por su índice
        for (i in layoutItems.indices) {
            // Obtener el id del item
            val idCheckBox = layoutItems[i].id
            // Los items sin "@id" son -1, aquí se filtran.
            if (idCheckBox >= 0) {
                // Obtener el id del checkbox actual
                val checkBoxItem: CheckBox = layoutItems.findViewById(idCheckBox)
                // Si está checked se añade a la lista de seleccionados
                if (checkBoxItem.isChecked) {
                    checksSelect.add(checkBoxItem.text.toString())
                }
            }
        }
        // Comprobar en el logcat que están todos los valores marcados
        checksSelect.forEach {  s ->
            Log.i("tag", s)
        }
    }

Lo que necesito es poder seleccionar de la vista solo los CheckBox, ya que de la forma como lo he hecho, se recorren todas los items de la vista que se le pasa y no sólo los checkBox, en este caso, todo lo de un LinearLayout. El problema es que hay un TextView al cual no se le puede pasar una id (android:id="@+id/tv_pruebas") porque al recorrer los items por el indice, te da un indice mayor de -1 y al comprobar "isChecked" crashea el programa.
¿Hay alguna forma de recorrer todos los items de un sólo tipo?

No recorras los elementos por índice, mejor obtén todos los elementos hijos que tiene tu Linearlayout. agregué respuesta.

Se supone que uses findViewById una sola vez (en el método onCreate) y guardes las referencias para luego

Lo más óptimo es iterar sobre los elementos que se encuentran en tu LinearLayout por su índice, y detectar cuáles son instancias de tipo CheckBox.
Para iterar los elementos que tiene tu layout usa getChildCount() , que obtiene la cantidad de hijos y luego verificas si cada hijo es una instancia de CheckBox, realiza el cambio:
binding.btnEnviar.setOnClickListener {
    
       // Guardar valores de los campos
        ... 
        // Crear una lista para guardar lo items
        val checksSelect = ArrayList<String>()
        // Meter en una variable los items de la vista.
        val layoutItems = binding.llOpciones
    
     // Recorrer los items...
    for (i in 0 until layoutItems.childCount) {//* Obten los elementos hijos del LinearLayout
    
        val child = layoutItems.getChildAt(i)
        
        if (child is CheckBox) { //* valida si es tipo CheckBox
            // Si está checked se añade a la lista de seleccionados
            if (child.isChecked) {
                checksSelect.add(child.text.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    // Comprobar en el logcat que están todos los valores marcados
    checksSelect.forEach { s ->
        Log.i("tag", s)
    }
}


¡¡¡GENIAL!!! Es exactamente lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias.
